# Boost ASIO. Прием по UDP.

Tags: c++, boost, udp, asio

Привет всем, возникла необходимость принимать пакеты с 4-х устройств по протоколу UDP. 
Использую для этого boost::asio. 
Проблема в следующем: при рассылке используется broadcast, при подключении к устройствам и приеме я получаю одинаковые(!) пакеты данных от всех, хотя через wireshark видно, что отсылаются разные. Вот пример как я пытаюсь принимать данные:

```
io_service service;
ip::udp::socket sock_mu(service); 
ip::udp::socket sock_s1(service); 
ip::udp::endpoint ep_m(ip::address::from_string("0.0.0.0"), port);  
ip::udp::endpoint ep_s1(ip::address::from_string("0.0.0.0"), port); 
sock_mu.open(boost::asio::ip::udp::v4()); 
sock_s1.open(boost::asio::ip::udp::v4());
sock_mu.set_option(boost::asio::socket_base::broadcast(true)); 
sock_s1.set_option(boost::asio::socket_base::broadcast(true)); 
sock_mu.set_option(boost::asio::ip::udp::socket::reuse_address(true));
sock_s1.set_option(boost::asio::ip::udp::socket::reuse_address(true));
sock_mu.bind(ep_m);
sock_mu.bind(ep_s1);
ip::udp::endpoint ep1(ip::address::from_string("192.162.2.101"), port);  
ip::udp::endpoint ep2(ip::address::from_string("192.168.2.102"), port);
sock_mu.receive_from(boost::asio::buffer(buf_m2, 16384), ep1);
sock_s1.receive_from(boost::asio::buffer(buf_m2, 16384), ep2);
```

Порт и IP адреса устройств указаны верно. При попытке делать connect к нужному IP адресу устройства пакеты не получаю вообще. Т.е. bind к любому (0.0.0.0) адресу работает, но получаю я одни и те же пакеты. А connect (192.168.2.101) например - нет.
Надеюсь объяснил понятно) Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1):

Здесь:

```
sock_mu.bind(ep_m);
sock_mu.bind(ep_s1);
```

Дважды подряд идет бинд одного и того же сокета.

`receive_from` вторым аргументом принимает `endpoint`, который будет установлен в адрес/порт отправителя полученной дейтаграммы. Т.е. их установка: `ip::udp::endpoint ep1(ip::address::from_string("192.162.2.101"), port);` не имеет смысла.

Также `receive_from` блокирует выполнение пока не получит дейтаграмму. Возможно вам нужны асинхронные функции вместо неё (зависит от логики вашего приложения).

Если задумка была в том, чтобы создать два сокета, сбиндить их на один порт, и в каждом получать дейтаграммы только от определенного клиента, то нужно:

- вызвать метод сокета [connect](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_datagram_socket/connect/overload1.html) передав в качестве параметра конечную точку удаленного устройства
- вызвать метод [receive](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_datagram_socket/receive/overload1.html) сокета (не receive_from), чтобы получить информацию.

В вашей ситуации возможно лучше будет использовать один сокет, который будет принимать дейтаграммы с помощью `receive_from` от всех клиентов, и по результату определять кто отправил дейтаграмму.

Comment: Это опечатка, в программе бинд на разные сокеты.

Comment: И метод receive_from дял каждого сокета выполянется в отдельном потоке (используется boost::thread)

Comment: При вызове метода connect и метода receive - данные не приходят, так я делал изначально

Comment: Однако, задумку вы поняли правильно, только устройств 4, и по содержимому пакетов невозможно понять с какого устройства пришли данные.

Comment: Ремарка: получаю пакеты разные. Но на сокет, для которого вызывается метод receive_from с конечной точкой с адресом 192.168.2.101 приходят пакеты с адреса 192.168.2.102. Я либо неверно подключаюсь, либо неверно принимаю данные. Помогите пожалуйста)

Comment: Т.е. я могу использовать один сокет , который биндится на любой адрес (0.0.0.0) и нужный мне порт. А дальше необходимо принять данные с определенного IP. receive_from не помогает, есть ли другие способы это сделать? Напомню, что при создании отдельных сокетов для каждого IP и вызове метода receive программа виснет в момент приема, не выкидывая даже исключения.

Comment: @Иван вам следует внимательнее прочитать описание `receive_from`, этот метод принимает данные с любого адреса, т.е. то, что вы передаете во втором параметре, она игнорирует, т.к. он предназначен для возврата результата.

Comment: Ок, спасибо. А не подскажете, в чем тогда причина того, что при последовательном вызове методов connect и receive для сокета и конечной точки с нужным адресом данные не принимаются? Может пропустил чего?

Comment: @Иван Судя по комментарием, приведенный вами в вопросе код отличается от реально используемого, поэтому сложно сказать.

Comment: код достаточно длинный, приведенный код - это то, что относится именно к сокетам, все написано в той последовательности, что и выполняется.

Comment: Если вы взглянете на код полностью, есть вероятность, что вы поможете? И есть ли у вас на это время и желание?

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решил. 
Сначала вызывается метод bind сокета, параметр - конечная точка с любым адресом (0.0.0.0). Потом - метод connect этого же сокета, параметр - конечная точка с нужным адресом. Вроде работает.
Спасибо за ответы!

Comment: Нет, не решил (